# iOS - Display PDF with signature

Tags: ios, pdf, digital-signature

I'm trying to display signed pdf in an iOS applications.

While displaying a PDF is easy (plenty of libraries, UIDocumentInteractionController, etc.), I can't seem to find how to display the signatures in the PDF.

By signature, I mean what is in this sample: http://blogs.adobe.com/security/SampleSignedPDFDocument.pdf

I've seen it done in an iOS application, but I've no idea how to do it myself. I tried poking around with `CGContextDrawPDFPage`, without much success.

Any hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signature you saw in the PDF file is the appearance of the signature field widget. The field widget is a specific PDF annotation. 
The problem with the default PDF rendering engine in iOS (used by UIDocumentInteractionController, QuickLook framework, etc) is that it does not display the annotations on the PDF page, it displays only the main page content.
The only solution is to use a 3rd party PDF rendering engine, such as MuPDF, Foxit, PDFTron, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Are you converting HTML to PDF? 
If yes then it may be helpful :)

```
 UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imgapplicationSignature.bounds.size);
        [imgapplicationSignature.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

        UIImage *image1 = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
        [self saveImage:image1 :@"imgapplicationSignature.png"];
        NSString *documentsDirectory1 = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask,YES)[0];
        [wbView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"var imageElement = document.getElementById('img_01'); imageElement.setAttribute('src', '%@');", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"file://%@/imgapplicationSignature.png", documentsDirectory1]]];
```